# connected ssh to AWS EC2 instance get stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am running AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16.* based) . The problem is when I connect instance using ssh terminal (ssh -i "my_app.pem" ubuntu@my_IP ) to cofigure the instance, after some time my terminal get stuck and I cannot do anything else in this terminal tab, just to close it, and have to connect again in another tab. It happens every 10 minutes. Could you help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Putty](https://www.putty.org) to [connect to EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html).
Then use the following setting to keep session alive. Read more [here](https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/getting-started-guide/accessing-your-account/keeping-ssh-connections-alive)

[image]